# Compile Objective-C under Ubuntu

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gcc, makefile, compilation

I found the following project:
https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli

I would like to make this available for Linux as well. Unfortunately, I don't know much about Objective-C. Since the project was probably developed under Mac and XCode there are no Makefiles.

Unfortunately I don't know how where i should start. I did some research on the internet, but I did not manage to compile the files.

I am running on Ubuntu.

Comment: Objective-C is different from C++. It there C++ involved in the project somehow?

Comment: No its all Objective-C - But you use gcc/g++ to compile it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708566

Comment: Okay, then I'm going to remove the C++ tag, since it doesn't seem relevant to the question.